# Take screenshot hiding some widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to take a screenshot of a screen but I want to hide/blur/paint some Widgets in the resulting screenshot, but **not** in the app.
Something like this:

[image: What we see in the app]
[image: What I want to get in the screenshot]

The first picture is what I want to see in the app, no changes.
The second picture is what I want to see in the screenshot, a specific widget painted.

My first thought was to calculate absolute coordinates of the specific widget, but in order to do this, I should add a GlobalKey to each of the widgets of the screen, and this is not feasible for my case.

How to do this **without adding a GlobalKey** to each of the widgets of the screen?

My current approach for taking a screenshot is:

```
final pixelRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
final boundary = boundaryKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
final image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: pixelRatio);
```

This is what I'm using to get coordinates of a Widget that has a GlobalKey:

```
extension GlobalKeyExtension on GlobalKey {
  Rect? get globalPaintBounds {
    final renderObject = currentContext?.findRenderObject();
    var translation = renderObject?.getTransformTo(null).getTranslation();
    if (translation != null) {
      return renderObject!.paintBounds
          .shift(Offset(translation.x, translation.y));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to declare:

```
bool _hideWidget = false;
```

Next you this value with all widgets that you want to hide while taking screenshot:

```
floatingActionButton: _hideWidget ? const SizedBox.shrink() : FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _incrementCounter,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
```

In method that you use for taking screenshot, use next:

```
Future takeScreenShot() async {
    final RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = previewContainer.currentContext!.findRenderObject()! as RenderRepaintBoundary;

    if (boundary.debugNeedsPaint) {
      print("Waiting for boundary to be painted.");
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 20));
      return takeScreenShot();
    }

    setState(() {
      _hideWidget = !_hideWidget;
    });
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    final ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 5);
    final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    final ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    final Uint8List pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();
    File imgFile = File('$directory/screenshot.png');
    print('$directory/screenshot.png');
    imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    setState(() {
      _hideWidget = !_hideWidget;
    });
  }
```

PS: in asynchronius methods you must use FutureDelayed for properly working of SetState

Answer (score 0):

[screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) widget is what you are looking for.

In your pubspec.yaml file add the following line under dependencies

```
dependencies:
  screenshot: ^0.3.0
```

Then you can use it like so. I just added some buttons and containers to show case it. You can customize it for your needs. Basically what this does is When you put a widget as a child of a Screenshot widget with a controller, you can capture it as an image.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';

class ScreenCapture extends StatefulWidget {
  ScreenCapture({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScreenCaptureState createState() => _ScreenCaptureState();
}

class _ScreenCaptureState extends State<ScreenCapture> {
  Uint8List _imageFile;
  Color captureColor = Colors.red, inAppColor = Colors.green, inAppImageBG;
  String capturingText = "Capturing State";
  String inAppDisplayText = "In App Display";
  String inAppText;
  ScreenshotController screenshotController = new ScreenshotController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    inAppImageBG = inAppColor;
    inAppText = inAppDisplayText;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [capturedImageContainer(), inAppImage(), capture()],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget capturedImageContainer() {
    return _imageFile != null
        ? Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            height: 100,
            width: 300,
            child: Image.memory(_imageFile),
          )
        : Container(color: Colors.black, height: 100, width: 300);
  }

  Widget inAppImage() {
    return Screenshot(
      controller: screenshotController,
      child: Container(
        color: inAppImageBG,
        height: 100,
        width: 300,
        child: Text(inAppText),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget capture() {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        doCapture();
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 300,
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: Text("Capture"),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
      ),
    );
  }

  doCapture() async {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      setState(() {
        inAppImageBG = captureColor;
        inAppText = capturingText + Random().nextInt(10).toString();
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10), () {
          screenshotController
              .capture(delay: Duration(milliseconds: 1))
              .then((Uint8List image) async {
            setState(() {
              _imageFile = image;
              Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1500), () {
                setState(() {
                  inAppImageBG = inAppColor;
                  inAppText = inAppDisplayText;
                });
              });
            });
          }).catchError((onError) {
            print(onError);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. I've already tried this approach, but it doesn't allow me to hide or paint the screenshot without changing the UI on the app at the same time, so it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @CarlosMacMar Did you find a solution for this